# Laravel 5.8: The items.0.id field is required. Error

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade

estoy trabajando en una aplicación para la empresa en la que trabajo, esta apliación se realizó utilizando Laravel 5.8 y MySQL. He logrado incorporar mejoras y demás pero hay algo que aún no logro resolver (soy programador junior y aun no tengo tanta experiencia). El tema es que existe una relación muchos a muchos, necesito hacer que en la vista edit de un proyecto se puedan relacionar nuevos items al proyecto con sus respectivas cantidades, a su vez debe ser posible desenlazar items antiguamente relacionados si asi se necesitara. Pero sin embargo al intentar hacerlo, la vista me responde con el siguiente error: The items.0.id field is required.The items.0.quantity field is required.

A continuación el código:

ProjectController:

```
public function edit($id)
    {
        $project = Project::findOrFail($id);
        $items = Item::all();
        $project_items = $project->items()->pluck('id')->toArray();
        $project_items_quantity = $project->items()->pluck('quantity', 'id')->toArray();
        $item_project = ItemProject::where('project_id', $id)->get();

        return view('includes.edit_delete_project',
            compact('items', 'project_items', 'project_items_quantity', 'item_project'))
            ->with(['project'=> Project::getProjectById($id),
            'entities'=>Entity::getEntities(),
                'countries'=>Country::getCountries()]);
    }

    public function update(Request $request, Project $project)
    {
        $this->validate($request, array(
            'code' => 'required|string|max:255',
            'entity' => 'required|string|max:255',
            'country' => 'required|string|max:255',
            'items' => 'nullable|array',
            'items.*.id' => 'required|integer|exists:items,id',
            'items.*.quantity' => 'required|integer|min:0',
        ));

        $project->update($request->only(['code', 'entity', 'country']));

        if ($request->has('items')) {
            $items = $request->input('items');

            $currentItems = $project->items->pluck('id')->toArray();
            $detachItems = array_diff($currentItems, array_column($items, 'id'));
            $project->items()->detach($detachItems);

            foreach ($items as $item) {
                $project->items()->syncWithoutDetaching([$item['id'] => ['quantity' => $item['quantity']]]);
            }
        }

        return response()->json($project);
    }
```

Project Model:

```
class Project extends Model
{
    protected $table = "project";

    protected $fillable = ['code',
        'entity',
        'country'];
    protected $hidden = ['id'];

    public static function getProjects()
    {
        return Project::all();
    }

    public static function getProjectById($id)
    {
        return Project::find($id);
    }

    public function items()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Item::class, 'project_item',
            'project_id', 'item_id')->withPivot('quantity');
    }
}
```

Project edit view:

```
<!-- Edit -->
<div class="modal fade" id="edit{{$project->id}}">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                <h4 class="modal-title"><b><span class="employee_id">Edit Project</span></b></h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <form class="form-horizontal" method="POST" action="/includes/edit_delete_project/{{ $project->id }}">
                    @csrf
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="code" class="col-sm-3 control-label"><span style="color: red">*</span> Code</label>

                        <div class="col-sm-9">
                            <input oninput="this.value = this.value.toUpperCase()" type="text" class="form-control"
                                   id="code" name="code" value="{{$project->code}}" required>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="entity" class="col-sm-3 control-label"><span style="color: red">*</span> Company</label>

                        <div class="col-sm-9">
                            <select class="form-control" id="entity" name="entity" required>
                                <option value="" selected>{{collect($entities)->where('id', $project->entity)->first()->company}}</option>
                                @foreach($entities as $entity)
                                    <option value="{{$entity->id}}">{{$entity->company}} </option>
                                @endforeach
                            </select>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="country" class="col-sm-3 control-label"><span style="color: red">*</span> Country</label>

                        <div class="col-sm-9">
                            <select class="form-control" id="country" name="country" required>
                                <option value="" selected>{{collect($countries)->where('id', $project->country)->first()->iso}}</option>
                                @foreach($countries as $country)
                                    <option value="{{$country->id}}">{{$country->name}} </option>
                                @endforeach
                            </select>
                        </div>
                    </div>


                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="items" class="col-sm-3 control-label"><span style="color: red"></span> Items</label>

                        <div class="col-sm-9">
                            @foreach($items as $item)
                                <div class="form-check">
                                    <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" name="items[]" value="{{ $item->id }}" id="item{{ $item->id }}">
                                    <label class="form-check-label" for="item{{ $item->id }}">{{ $item->pn }} - {{ $item->detail }}</label>

                                    <input type="number"
                                           class="form-control"
                                           min="1"
                                           style="width: 100px;"
                                           id="quantity_{{$item->id}}"
                                           name="quantity_{{$item->id}}"
                                           value="{{old('quantity_' . $item->id)}}" placeholder="Quantity">
                                </div>
                            @endforeach
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-flat pull-left" data-dismiss="modal"><i
                                class="fa fa-close"></i> Close
                        </button>
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-flat" name="edit"><i class="fa fa-check-square-o"></i>
                            Update
                        </button>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

He intentado varias recomendaciones de internet pero aun no he tenido exito con ninguna. Es lo único que me hace falta de todo lo que me solicitaron para ya dar por finalizada la aplicación.
Solo necesito resolver lo que expuse al inicio y estaré muy agradecido a quien pueda ayudarme.

Comment: Fijate el nombre del input `" name="items[]"` pero estas intentando validar `items.*.id`. No coinciden, al nombre del input le falta ese `id` al final. Prueba cambiarlo a `name="items[]id"`. Lo mismo te estaria pasando para el input `name="quantity_{{$item->id`